# Javascript Runcode Appear Null

Tags: javascript, html, null

I am trying to make a code editor from a code editior
Here is my code below

```
<input id='code'></input>
<button onclick="runcode()">Run Code</button>
<script>
window.onerror = function(error) {
  // do something clever here
  alert("ERROR"); // do NOT do this for real!
};
var asdf = document.getElementById('Code');
function runcode() {
    console.log(document.write(asdf))
}
</script>
```

The problem is, when I run a piece of code like `＜p＞Hello World＜/p＞` the result is Null

Comment: What do you mean "make a code editor from a code editor"?

Comment: There are lots of mistakes here. `<input>` elements are self-closing, you don't need `</input>` -- are you thinking of `<textarea>`? `document.write(asdf)` makes no sense, `adsf` is a DOM element, not a string; you need `asdf.value`. `Code` should be `code`.

Comment: Well, I use an online code editor and am trying to create a code editor

Comment: How you created the code is not really relevant. Code is code no matter where it comes from.

Comment: :o wow... I am apparentally horrible at html and javascript... it works now thanks :D